# Compilation error in LLVM when passing parameter of type std::vector<StructType*>

Tags: c++, llvm

When using LLVM 3.1, I want to invoke the function `findUsedStructTypes`, which is declared in the class `Module` of the file `include/llvm/Module.h`:

```
/// findUsedStructTypes - Walk the entire module and find all of the
/// struct types that are in use, returning them in a vector.
void findUsedStructTypes(std::vector<StructType*> &StructTypes) const;
```

Given `M` is a variable of the class `Module`, my actual code to invoke the above function is:

```
std::vector<llvm::StructType*> all_structs;
M.findUsedStructTypes(all_structs);
```

However, when compiling, there is an error thrown up:

```
undefined reference to `llvm::Module::findUsedStructTypes(std::vector<llvm::StructType*, std::allocator<llvm::StructType*> >&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am new to LLVM and haven't experienced much with C++, hence couldn't figure out why there is such error.

Can anybody help to explain what is wrong with my code?

Thanks for spending your time to look at my question.

Comment: Are you linking to a proper library?

Comment: I think I did link properly. I use Rtags (https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags) which uses the same build system, to jump to the definition of `findUsedStructTypes` as copied above.

Comment: I discovered that I used a modified version of LLVM, and whereas header file `Module.h` still contains that function, the implementation file `Module.cpp` doesn't has anymore. This is why the compilation fails.